# How to remove item from onsen list?

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

i use onsen list in mobile application.now i need remove item of list in js. but i do not know?
can help me?
Thanks and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example you could remove an element...

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_elementremove

Maybe it'll help?